# When finding Modulus of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ is a complex number and $a$ is a real number then can we say $|az| = a|z|$? Here, $|z|$ refers to the modulus of $z$.

Comment: Almost. What if $a$ is negative?

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be real and $z$ be complex. Then there exists $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $z=x+iy$. So, $az = a(x+iy) = ax+i(ay)$ which implies

$$|az| = \sqrt{(ax)^2+(ay)^2} = \sqrt{a^2(x^2 + y^2)} = |a| \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = |a| |z|.$$

Answer (score 0):

$|az|=|a||z|$ where $|a|$ is just the absolute value of $a$ when $a$ is real.

If you want to prove this, we know that $|w|=\sqrt{\Re^2 w+\Im^2 w}$, thus $$|az|=\sqrt{\Re^2(az)+\Im^2(az)}=\sqrt{a^2(\Re^2 z+\Im^2 z)}$$
can you finish this?

Answer (score 0):

If $z=x+iy,  w=a+ib,$

$zw=(xa-yb)+i(bx+ay),|zw|=\cdots=|z||w|$

Now if $b=0,$

$$|zw|=|z|\sqrt{a^2}$$

We know $$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$$